# Evaluate expression with local variables

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I'm writing a genetic program in order to test the fitness of randomly generated expressions. Shown here is the function to generate the expression as well a the main function. DIV and GT are defined elsewhere in the code:

```
function create_single_full_tree(depth, fs, ts)                                                                                                                                         
"""                                                                                                                                                                                 
Creates a single AST with full depth                                                                                                                                                
Inputs                                                                                                                                                                              
    depth   Current depth of tree. Initially called from main() with max depth                                                                                                      
    fs      Function Set - Array of allowed functions                                                                                                                               
    ts      Terminal Set - Array of allowed terminal values                                                                                                                         
Output                                                                                                                                                                              
    Full AST of typeof()==Expr                                                                                                                                                      
"""                                                                                                                                                                                 

# If we are at the bottom                                                                                                                                                           
if depth == 1                                                                                                                                                                       
    # End of tree, return function with two terminal nodes                                                                                                                          
    return Expr(:call, fs[rand(1:length(fs))], ts[rand(1:length(ts))], ts[rand(1:length(ts))])                                                                                      
else                                                                                                                                                                                
    # Not end of expression, recurively go back through and create functions for each new node                                                                                      
    return Expr(:call, fs[rand(1:length(fs))], create_single_full_tree(depth-1, fs, ts), create_single_full_tree(depth-1, fs, ts))                                                  
end                                                                                                                                                                                 
end                                                                                                                                                                                     

function main()                                                                                                                                                                         
    """                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Main function                                                                                                                                                                       
    """                                                                                                                                                                                 

    # Define functional and terminal sets                                                                                                                                               
    fs = [:+, :-, :DIV, :GT]                                                                                                                                                            
    ts = [:x, :v, -1]                                                                                                                                                                   
    # Create the tree                                                                                                                                                                   
    ast = create_single_full_tree(4, fs, ts)                                                                                                                                            
    #println(typeof(ast))                                                                                                                                                               
    #println(ast)                                                                                                                                                                       
    #println(dump(ast))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    x = 1                                                                                                                                                                               
    v = 1                                                                                                                                                                               
    eval(ast)  # Error out unless x and v are globals                                                                                                                                                                  
end                                                                                                                                                                                     
main()
```

I am generating a random expression based on certain allowed functions and variables.  As seen in the code, the expression can only have symbols x and v, as well as the value -1.  I will need to test the expression with a variety of x and v values; here I am just using x=1 and v=1 to test the code.

The expression is being returned correctly, however, eval() can only be used with global variables, so it will error out when run unless I declare x and v to be global (ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: x not defined).  I would like to avoid globals if possible. Is there a better way to generate and evaluate these generated expressions with locally defined variables?

Comment: Maybe it is possible to create the AST of a function with input arguments (instead of the AST of a expression) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for generating an (anonymous) function. The result of eval can be called as a function and your variable can be passed as parameters:

```
myfun = eval(Expr(:->,:x,  Expr(:block, Expr(:call,:*,3,:x) )))
myfun(14)
# returns 42
```

The `dump` function is very useful to inspect the expression that the parsers has created. For two input arguments you would use a tuple for example as `args[1]`:

```
  julia> dump(parse("(x,y) -> 3x + y"))
  Expr
    head: Symbol ->
    args: Array{Any}((2,))
      1: Expr
        head: Symbol tuple
        args: Array{Any}((2,))
          1: Symbol x
          2: Symbol y
        typ: Any
      2: Expr
 [...]
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Metaprogramming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/) part of the Julia documentation, there is a sentence under the **`eval()` and effects** section which says

> Every `module` has its own `eval()` function that evaluates expressions in its global scope.

Similarly, the REPL help `?eval` will give you, on Julia 0.6.2, the following help:

> Evaluate an expression in the given module and return the result. Every `Module` (except those defined with `baremodule`) has its own 1-argument definition of `eval`, which evaluates expressions in that module.

I assume, you are working in the `Main` module in your example. That's why you need to have the globals defined there. For your problem, you can use `macro`s and interpolate the values of `x` and `y` directly inside the macro.

A minimal working example would be:

```
macro eval_line(a, b, x)
  isa(a, Real) || (warn("$a is not a real number."); return :(throw(DomainError())))
  isa(b, Real) || (warn("$b is not a real number."); return :(throw(DomainError())))
  return :($a * $x + $b) # interpolate the variables
end
```

Here, `@eval_line` macro does the following:

```
Main> @macroexpand @eval_line(5, 6, 2)
:(5 * 2 + 6)
```

As you can see, the values of `macro`'s arguments are interpolated inside the macro and the expression is given to the user accordingly. When the user does not behave,

```
Main> @macroexpand @eval_line([1,2,3], 7, 8)
WARNING: [1, 2, 3] is not a real number.
:((Main.throw)((Main.DomainError)()))
```

a user-friendly warning message is provided to the user at *parse*-time, and a `DomainError` is thrown at run-time.

Of course, you can do these things within your functions, again by interpolating the variables --- you do *not* need to use `macro`s. However, what you would like to achieve in the end is to combine `eval` with the output of a function that returns `Expr`. This is what the `macro` functionality is for. Finally, you would simply call your `macro`s with an `@` sign preceding the `macro` name:

```
Main> @eval_line(5, 6, 2)
16
Main> @eval_line([1,2,3], 7, 8)
WARNING: [1, 2, 3] is not a real number.
ERROR: DomainError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
```

**EDIT 1.** You can take this one step further, and create functions accordingly:

```
macro define_lines(linedefs)
  for (name, a, b) in eval(linedefs)
    ex = quote
      function $(Symbol(name))(x) # interpolate name
        return $a * x + $b # interpolate a and b here
      end
    end
    eval(ex) # evaluate the function definition expression in the module
  end
end
```

Then, you can call this macro to create different line definitions in the form of functions to be called later on:

```
@define_lines([
  ("identity_line", 1, 0);
  ("null_line", 0, 0);
  ("unit_shift", 0, 1)
])

identity_line(5) # returns 5
null_line(5) # returns 0
unit_shift(5) # returns 1
```

**EDIT 2.** You can, I guess, achieve what you would like to achieve by using a macro similar to that below:

```
macro random_oper(depth, fs, ts)
  operations = eval(fs)
  oper = operations[rand(1:length(operations))]
  terminals = eval(ts)
  ts = terminals[rand(1:length(terminals), 2)]
  ex = :($oper($ts...))
  for d in 2:depth
    oper = operations[rand(1:length(operations))]
    t = terminals[rand(1:length(terminals))]
    ex = :($oper($ex, $t))
  end
  return ex
end
```

which will give the following, for instance:

```
Main> @macroexpand @random_oper(1, [+, -, /], [1,2,3])
:((-)([3, 3]...))

Main> @macroexpand @random_oper(2, [+, -, /], [1,2,3])
:((+)((-)([2, 3]...), 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, see next post below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arda for the thorough response! This helped, but part of me thinks there may be a better way to do this as it seems too roundabout. Since I am writing a genetic program, I will need to create 500 of these ASTs, all with random functions and terminals from a set of allowed functions and terminals (fs and ts in the code).  I will also need to test each function with 20 different values of x and v.

In order to accomplish this with the information you have given, I have come up with the following macro:

```
macro create_function(defs)                                                                                       
        for name in eval(defs)                                                                                    
        ex = quote                                                                                                
            function $(Symbol(name))(x,v)                                                                         
                fs = [:+, :-, :DIV, :GT]                                                                          
                ts = [x,v,-1]                                                                                     
                return create_single_full_tree(4, fs, ts)                                                         
            end                                                                                                   
        end                                                                                                       
        eval(ex)                                                                                                  
    end                                                                                                           
end
```

I can then supply a list of 500 random function names in my main() function, such as ["func1, func2, func3,.....".  Which I can eval with any x and v values in my main function. This has solved my issue, however, this seems to be a very roundabout way of doing this, and may make it difficult to evolve each AST with each iteration.

Comment: I did _not_ say that you should define 500 different functions. I just showed that you _can_ define functions (or, closures with the same principle) if you want, with macros. Please check my modified answer.