# Conditional sum on edges in julia

Tags: julia, list-comprehension

I have a complex problem where I have to evaluate a sum on edges from a graph previously built.
Julia doesn't seem to handle conditional sum with edges.

Here is a simple problem similar to the one I am trying to solve:

```
module EssaiModule

using LightGraphs, MetaGraphs

g = DiGraph(6)
mg = MetaDiGraph(g, 1.0)
add_vertex!(mg)
add_edge!(mg,1,2)
add_edge!(mg,1,3)
add_edge!(mg,1,4)
add_edge!(mg,2,4)
add_edge!(mg,2,5)
add_edge!(mg,3,5)
add_edge!(mg,5,6)
add_edge!(mg,4,6)

set_props!(mg,3,Dict(:port=>1,:vessel=>2))
set_props!(mg,1,Dict(:port=>1,:vessel=>0))
set_props!(mg,2,Dict(:port=>1,:vessel=>0))
set_props!(mg,4,Dict(:port=>1,:vessel=>2))
set_props!(mg,5,Dict(:port=>0,:vessel=>2))
set_props!(mg,6,Dict(:port=>0,:vessel=>0))

SI = sum(1 for e in edges(mg);get_prop(g,dst(e),:vessel)==2 && get_prop(g,dst(e),:port)==1)

println(SI)

end
```

When I test it like that I get the error

```
#LoadError: MethodError: no method matching dst(::Irrational{:e})
```

I really need to figure out how to sum with conditions because in my real problem I am putting this sum in a constraint, like this with the sum on edges `ed` and `x` a variable:

```
@constraint(model, cM[e in edges(g)], x[e] + sum(x[ed] for ed in edges(g) ; fn1(ed) == 2 && fn2(ed) == 1) <= 1 + y)
```

and I have the error message saying

```
#LoadError: UndefVarError: ed not defined
```

So my questions are the following:

1. Why is the first code not working, since the type of `e` is `Int`?
2. Am I writing my constraint in a bad way?

I am sorry I can't upload the real problem, the content and the data are not to be put online, plus it is too big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you need to change your function call

```
SI = sum(1 for e in edges(mg);get_prop(g,dst(e),:vessel)==2 && get_prop(g,dst(e),:port)==1)
#                            ^ you end the statement with a semicolon
# after the semicolon, keyword arguments of a function, in this case `sum`,
# begins. then, the compiler checks the function `dst` and cannot find a proper
# method that is implemented for e, that is, the irrational number e.
```

to read as below:

```
SI = length([e for e in edges(mg) if get_prop(mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
                                     get_prop(mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1   ])

println(SI) # prints 3
```

Note also the typo in your code. `get_prop` *needs* to check `mg`, instead of `g`. You should also have a look at the [comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1) section of the documentation.

For the second part of your question, you should provide the macro definition for us to help you better. Most likely, you are not [interpolating](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#Interpolation-1) the expression/variable inside the macro. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49207720/4720025) to a different question and tell if that helps.

**EDIT 1.** Actually, you have *the same* problem in your second part, too. Inside `sum`, you end the positional arguments with the semicolon and start the [keyword arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#Keyword-Arguments-1).

**EDIT 2.** As per DNF's comment below, you should even use `count` for a more expressive (in source code) and efficient version:

```
SI = count(e->(get_prop(mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
               get_prop(mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1   ), edges(mg))
# or,
SI = count(get_prop(mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
           get_prop(mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1    for e in edges(mg))
```

**EDIT 3.** Performance comparison is below:

```
Pkg.add("BenchmarkTools")
using BenchmarkTools

@benchmark count(e->(get_prop(mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
                     get_prop(mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1   ), edges(mg))

BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  7.73 KiB
  allocs estimate:  53
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.201 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.494 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.191 μs (15.69% GC)
  maximum time:     198.515 μs (95.69% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9

@benchmark count(get_prop(mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
                 get_prop(mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1    for e in edges(mg))

BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  7.75 KiB
  allocs estimate:  54
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.352 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.661 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.712 μs (15.10% GC)
  maximum time:     236.440 μs (95.06% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9

@benchmark length([e for e in edges(mg) if get_prop(mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
                                           get_prop(mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1])

BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  8.13 KiB
  allocs estimate:  60
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.642 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.789 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.553 μs (14.54% GC)
  maximum time:     231.424 μs (94.73% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9
```

`count` version seems to be 10% more efficient than `length`, which can make a difference in your actual, bigger problem.

**EDIT 4.** The proper way to do the benchmarking is below, thanks to DNF, again:

```
@benchmark count(e->(get_prop($mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
                     get_prop($mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1   ), edges($mg))

BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  7.72 KiB
  allocs estimate:  52
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.320 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.478 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.952 μs (10.33% GC)
  maximum time:     117.306 μs (93.38% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9

@benchmark count(get_prop($mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 &&
                 get_prop($mg, dst(e), :port  ) == 1    for e in edges($mg))

BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  7.73 KiB
  allocs estimate:  53
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.340 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.524 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.030 μs (11.17% GC)
  maximum time:     197.018 μs (94.35% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9
```

Comment: It's more efficient and terse to use `count` here, without allocating an array. Instead of `length([n for n in coll if pred(n)])`, use `count(pred(n) for n in coll)` or `count(pred, coll)`, where `pred` is your predicate function.

Comment: Actually, you should use interpolation with `@benchmark`: as in `@benchmark count(pred, $coll)`. There should be zero allocations for the `count` implementation, and probably a much bigger speedup.

Comment: @DNF, I have updated it again. There doesnt seem to have any improvement with the interpolation. I am on `0.6.2`. Maybe you should run this and do it the proper way, and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, the way to do it is: `@benchmark count(e->(get_prop($mg, dst(e), :vessel) == 2 && get_prop($mg, dst(e), :port) == 1), edges($mg))`. However, I was wrong. There will still be allocations, not because of the iteration, but because `get_prop` etc. allocate. You get the minimum amount of allocations, compared to the array comprehension, but cannot avoid the intrinsic allocations of the graph code. Also, it isn't the looping that dominates the time use, so the speedups are modest. Sorry about the confusion :)

Comment: But in general, interpolating variables into benchmarking code is good practice, and you can often get dramatic slowdown if you don't do it, when the compiler cannot infer the variable types.

Comment: Thank you two for these dense and precise answers, I will try apply to apply all these to my code - Will let you know if I have further questions on this matter.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider `filter_edges` instead of calling `get_props` on each edge inside a comprehension: `filter_edges(mg, (g, e) -> get_prop(g, e, :vessel) == 2 && get_prop(g, e, :port) == 1)`.

Comment: @sbromberger I have made a benchmark on my final code and it seems this solution with filter_edges doesn't improve computation time rather than using a simple conditional sum, the model with sums is 1,5 times faster.
Thank you for you help all of you !